# CDATA tags break media queries in email CSS

Tags: css, gmail, html-email, cdata, bronto

We've noticed email platforms like Bronto add 
`/*<![CDATA[*`/ tags around the CSS inside `<style type="text/css">` in the `<head>`.

This seems to break media queries. If you can't remove those tags is there any technique to preserve the media queries in the CSS?

Edit: CSS from head tag. Everything works in Litmus tests and then in Bronto

```
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
                /* Based on The MailChimp Reset INLINE: Yes. */  
                /* Client-specific Styles */
                #outlook a {padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
                body{ max-width: 600px !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;} 
                /* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes.*/ 
                .ExternalClass {width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */  
                .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
                /* End reset */

                /* Some sensible defaults for images
                Bring inline: Yes. */
                img {outline:none; text-decoration:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;} 
                a img {border:none;} 
                .image_fix {display:block;}


                /* Hotmail header color reset
                Bring inline: Yes. */
                h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {color: black !important;}

                h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {color: blue !important;}

                h1 a:active, h2 a:active,  h3 a:active, h4 a:active, h5 a:active, h6 a:active {
                color: red !important; /* Preferably not the same color as the normal header link color.  There is limited support for psuedo classes in email clients, this was added just for good measure. */
                }

                h1 a:visited, h2 a:visited,  h3 a:visited, h4 a:visited, h5 a:visited, h6 a:visited {
                color: purple !important; /* Preferably not the same color as the normal header link color. There is limited support for psuedo classes in email clients, this was added just for good measure. */
                }

                /* Outlook 07, 10 Padding issue fix
                Bring inline: No.*/
                table td {border-collapse: collapse;}

    /* Remove spacing around Outlook 07, 10 tables
    Bring inline: Yes */
    table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; } 

.clearFloat { height:0; line-height:0; font-size:0; clear:both; overflow:hidden; }

.mobile { display: block; }
.standard { display:none; }

#maintable { max-width: 600px !important; }
#mainimage { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;  }


@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),  
       (min-moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
       (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

#maintable {width: 320px !important; }  
.mobile { display:block; }
.standard { display: none; }    

td[class="headercell"] {
        background-image: url(http://aaa_320.jpg);
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-position:center;
    }
td[class="headercell"] img { 
        display: none;
                visibility:hidden; 
    }

}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 768px)  {
  /* rules for iPad in landscape orientation */
#maintable {width: 600px; }
.mobile { display: none; }
.standard { display:block; }
.overlay-banner { display:none !important; visibility:hidden !important;}

td[class="headercell"] {
        background-image: url(http://aaa_600.jpg) !important;
                background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
                background-position:center !important;
}


}


/*]]>*/
</style>
```

Edit 2: It looks like the problem is related to Bronto's parsing of the email and unencoded character in the email body. The first is issue is begins after CDATA tags close, in the :

```
<td style="font-size: 10px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align:center; padding: 7px 0px 7px 0px;"><a href="http://app.bronto.com/public/?q=preview_message&fn=Link&t=1&ssid=432&id=agwmajpnhsj7fzetyfhllfrkilwj8&id2=aqf4i1irg6rpyamab1badjdynmrgc&subscriber_id=caulvlaikmcbywqgwfqdqxmsfhhebpo&messageversion_id=bhvfhigljqvqccuomafmrtacddzsboj&delivery_id=axenwkrevhaeugjsidrkgabifwtabfa&tid=3.AbA.CCJGeQ.DYmK.UiHM..mWut.t....a.UdSX2A.UdSX2A.4VG-Og" style="color:#4f545c;">If you have trouble viewing this e-mail click here.</a></td>
```

That line generates an `cannot generate system identifier for general entity "fn"` in W3C and an `htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'` in Litmus

Comment: But `/*<![CDATA[*/` is the recommended way, that is supposed to work on all platforms. Can you show some more of your source, i.e. the bit that works without the CDATA block?

Comment: Sure, I posted the CSS section and redacted only the URLs.

Comment: If I put that css into a simple HTML file, the media queries work normally. (The `min-width:768px` one that is; I can test that one by making the window wider and narrower.) So unless I'm missing something and you're trying this with a browser I haven't tested, I don't know what goes wrong in your case.

Comment: Updated the post, seems from W3C and Litmus, Bronto is causing character encoding issue when it parses the original email.